# Does Google Patent cover all Chinese patents records from SIPO or just those who applied for PCT?

Tags: pct, chinese-patent, google-patents

Can all patents records on SIPO website also be found from Google Patent search? Google Patent search says their patents originate from the United States Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO), the European Patent Office (EPO), and the World Intellectual Property Organization (WIPO). However, I also found some patent records from Chinese Patent Office (SIPO). Does Google Patent cover all patents from SIPO?

Answer (score 1):

You can know for sure that not only the Chinese patents and patent applications coming from the PCT Route are included in Google Patents because:

- The [Chinese document coverage](https://patents.google.com/coverage/CN) in Google Patents includes patent documents from 1985 and 1990.
- China became a [PCT Contracting State](https://www.wipo.int/pct/en/pct_contracting_states.html) in January 1994.
- Only international applications with a filing date on or after China became a PCT CS can enter into the Chinese national phase.

The [Espacenet database](https://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/technical/patent-additions.html) publishes the most recent Chinese patent documents earlier than Google Patents.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipeadia says that google patents covers the following but I would not assume that the coverage is 100% complete in any dimension.

> ```
> United States Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO),
> European Patent Office (EPO),
> China's National Intellectual Property Administration (CNIPA),
> Japan Patent Office (JPO),
> Korean Intellectual Property Office (KIPO),
> World Intellectual Property Organization (WIPO),
> Deutsches Patent- und Markenamt (DPMA),
> Canadian Intellectual Property Office (CIPO),
> Russia, UK, France, Spain, Belgium, Denmark, Finland, Luxembourg, the Netherlands.[1]
> ```